# Error Creating Assembly in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, assemblies

We are having problems creating an assembly in our database and need some assistance.  We have two .NET 2.0 assemblies (`ABC.Company.App1.dll` and `ABC.Company.App2.dll`).  Both assemblies only have references to System, System.Data, and System.XML.  ABC.Company.App1.dll also references ABC.Company.App2.dll.

We're trying to create the ABC.Company.App1.dll assembly using:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY App1 
AUTHORIZATION dbo 
FROM 'C:\ApplicationPath\ABC.Company.App1.dll' 
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO
```

Note both assemblies are in C:\ApplicationPath.

But this fails.  The error is:

> Msg 10300, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
>   Assembly 'ABC.Company.App1' references assembly 'ABC.Company.App2, version=0.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=null.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: version, culture or public key mismatch). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.

What's the problem?  How can we fix this?

The version of ABC.Company.App2 is definitely not 0.0.0.0.  We've tried creating the ABC.Company.App2 assembly into our database first, which succeeds, but trying to create ABC.Company.App1 assembly still fails.  A little more info.  We've tried with PERMISSION_SET = SAFE, UNSAFE, and EXTERNAL_ACCESS, none of which work.  And, these DLLs are not strongly named and are not registered in the GAC.

Help?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to create assembly ABC.Company.App1.dll which references ABC.Company.App2.dll but, since ABC.Company.App2.dll hasn't been created yet, you're getting an error. Try creating ABC.Company.App2.dll first.

Comment: If I try registering our App2.dll, which is neither strongly name nor registered in the GAC, the assembly is created in SQL Server with no problems.  That is, if we do:
 
CREATE ASSEMBLY [ABC.Company.App2] 
AUTHORIZATION dbo 
FROM 'C:\ApplicationPath\ABC.Company.App2.dll' 
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
 GO
 
the App2.dll is created as an assembly in SQL Server.  But, if we follow this with:
 
CREATE ASSEMBLY App1 
AUTHORIZATION dbo 
FROM 'C:\ApplicationPath\ABC.Company.App1.dll' 
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
 GO
 
where ABC.Company.App1.dll references ABC.Company.App2.dll, it still fails.

Thanks!

Comment: If memory serves me correctly, either a.) the assembly has to be strongly named OR b.) the database you are creating the assembly in has to be trustworthy. You can run an ALTER DATABASE command to set it to trustworthy.

Comment: Hi again Brian.  We have tried the trustworthy thing, but it didn't help.  I guess we can try the strong name option to see if that helps.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried deploying from the solution? You can also give it the strong name from there.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I eventually worked it out. I was referencing an x86 assembly on a 64 bit server. I rebuilt the referenced assembly as Any CPU, installed in on the server, re-added the reference to the project, rebuilt my project as Any CPU, and **then** SQL Server could resolve the reference and install the assembly.

A message along the lines of "You're referencing an assembly that's built for the wrong platform" would have been rather useful :)